# ASP.NET MVC date are not been displayed View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, time, format, data-annotations

Almost working. Only one problem still remains.

This fields have not been displayed in the corresponding iput fields while loading my "View"

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Ínicio do contrato")]
public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Fim do contrato")]
public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }
```

This model properties are not empty, but don't appear in View

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataFim, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataFim, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataFim, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

I Found out the solution of Entity Frame work Problem.

This is the error message:

An error occurred while processing your request. Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

It is caused by ausence of field to represent the Primary Key of register in View while editing register.

His can be solved by putting Hidden input of primary key.

@Html.HiddenFieldFor(model => model.ID)

Doing this, it will fill missing key, and every thing works fine.

Comment: I forgot to say, the input value was "18:00"

Comment: Please edit your question and question title to reflect your specific issue.

Comment: *I tried to change the format in model to HH:mm, hh:mm but didn't worked*?? can you explain more clearly?

Comment: I'm trying to use 24 hours format, but "hh" (lowcase) represents 12 hours format, right?

Comment: correct, in order to use 24 hour format, the `hh` needs to be `HH`

Comment: also in your model, you are formatting as `hh:mm:ss` but your input only has `18:00`.. needs to be `18:00:00` to pass validation on the model

Comment: I'm guessing from the strings that perhaps your native language is Portuguese. There is a site, [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/), which might help you in that language.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Thanks. I posted a question in pt.stackoverflow.com, but I didn't get any helpful answer there until this moment.

Comment: It seems that the reason for not display date is an restiction of browser. I made a test, a and it appears on Chrome only if I specify the format "yyyy-MM-dd". Using @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataInicio, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date", @class = "form-control" }) works and chrome display in my language format ("dd/MM/yyyy"), but in firefox display exatly the same format as passed ("yyyy-MM-dd"). Maybe this is restriction of calendar on Chrome, since in Firefox this calendar does not exists. It seems I'll have to identify browser type and create input field according to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

your DataFormatString includes the seconds {0:hh:mm:ss}

Id also use DateType instead and you can avoid the regex

This will work for what you need

Model

```
    [Display(Name ="Horário de entrada")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan? HorarioEntrada { get; set; }
```

or try this regex

```
"((([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?)"
```

Comment: Using [DataType(DataType.Time)] Annotation transformed input text field in Hour format. It solved last problem but brought new one: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions. I'm reading this link to understand what is going wrong

Comment: I think that will be a data access layer issue separate to this

Comment: Following your sugestion, I decided to remove all regex to validate Date and Time fields. I think that was my problem. But now I´m not able to fill the date field with the value saved on database. In database has "16/11/1983" value, but the field keeps empty. 
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Ínicio do contrato")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing validation because as your question states.. you are inputting `18:00` which is Hour and Minute.

In your model, your string is formatted to `hh:mm:ss` which is hour, minute, and second.  So your input is not going to pass validation because `18:00` is missing an extra `:00` for seconds.

So, you need to change your input to `18:00:00` to pass validation.

Also, for 24 hour formatting, you need `HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: I want to keep user interface with HH:mm format, but in database the value is saved in HH:mm:ss format. This would be a problem to bind data? I chaged the model field to the format without seconds: [DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Display(Name ="Horário de entrada")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:HH\:mm}")]
public TimeSpan? HorarioEntrada { get; set; }

Comment: @OtavioCamargo no it shouldn't be a problem to bind data.  If your format is just `HH:mm` then when it is saved to database, it will just add a `:00` to that property for seconds.  Why do you have a `\` in your `HH:mm`?

Comment: @OtavioCamargo sorry `\\`

Comment: I haven't seen. I removed, but the errror still happens

Comment: @OtavioCamargo what did you try?

Comment: @OtavioCamargo In your update, in your model you have this `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:HH:mm}")]
        public TimeSpan? HorarioEntrada { get; set; }` your DataFormatString still does not include seconds and milliseconds apparently.. from what you are telling us you entered (HorarioEntrada (time): 09:00:00.0000000)

Comment: I removed "\" to verify if it was the problem cause. I edited question to put the updated code.

Comment: This is how appears in DataBase: 09:00:00.0000000, but in the view, I put in the format that I want to make it work: HH:mm

Comment: @OtavioCamargo okay then how are you entering it in the form?

Comment: I'm putting in the same format: "HH:mm". I think I'll have some problems with stackoverflow politics. I'm receiving this warning."Please avoid extended discussions in comments." Is there any way to post replys?

Comment: just hit continue this in chat

Comment: just to be clear, so you are entering `HH:mm` and you are receiving error?

Comment: Yes, I'm receiving error when binding data from data base to input field.

Comment: *when binding data from data base to input field*? do you mean when binding data from input field to database?

Comment: I mean bring database stored value to present it in MVC View input field for user to edit it.

Comment: ahh okay, so when you go to `Edit` view, you receive the error before the page ever loads?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The exception occurs while loading the edit page.

Comment: does it load if you take the `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:HH:mm}")]` off of the property in model?

Comment: this is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @OtavioCamargo awesome. glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem.
When I specifyed input field type by data annotation, It's not needed any other instruction to validate data like RegexExpression or DisplayFormat.
Theese combination of data annotation in my code was causing all problems.
By removing them, the user interface works correctly.
But as mentioned, changing the input types caused error in Entity Framework when passing values from ViewModel to EntityModel to update data on data base.
But, as @Joshua Duxbury mentioned, it might be other problem.
Thanks everyone.